# How to make background-img round and put into center?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my background-img round and put it into center. I am trying with code given below:

```
.jumbotronhh
    {
        background-image: url('http://simplelize.com/wp   content/uploads/2013/03/old-camera-620x350.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 50%;   
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;    *//If I don't use this line then the background picture stays in center in a rectangular form but after using this I got the bg-img circle but it moves at the left side of the screen..*  
    }
```

what to do?! I am totally novice.. pls help..

Comment: Can you add the full code to reproduce your issue please.

Comment: You can't use border-radius on a background image...only elements. An image of the desired result would be useful.

Comment: i know img will work here but I'm trying to do with bg-img, is it impossible? :(

Comment: Yes, it's impossible to affect background images in that way.

Comment: can you add `margin:0 auto` to that div and check

Answer (score 1):

You could put the image behind everything else to look like an actual background-image, by creating a div class and setting some z-index.

```
<div class="bg-image">
   <img src="mybackground.jpg">
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.bg-image {
   position: relative;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: auto;
}

.bg-image img {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   z-index: -100;
   border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}
```

Since you really can't use the `border-radius` in `background` properties.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with another picture and it works fine

Let me know if you mean another thing.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="jumbotronhh"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.jumbotronhh
{
    background-image: url('http://goo.gl/amTgah');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;   
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px; 
}
```